# PostgresSQL COPY command how to handle null

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am using AWS Aurora database, and try to copy data (CSV format) from S3 bucket to a table with the following command:

```sql
SELECT 
  aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 (
    'public.pmdocs', 
    '', 
    '(format csv, NULL ' NULL ')', 
    (
      SELECT 
        aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
          'yardi-backup', 'pmdocs.csv', 'us-east-1'
        )
    ), 
    aws_commons.create_aws_credentials(
      'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', ''
    )
  );
```

I know the back end function is COPY command, I keep getting a syntax error:

> Syntax error at or near "NULL"

Please advise how to fix this issue.

Comment: You have to write two single quotes (`''`) to get a single quote inside a string literal.